# how to escape single quotes in paramterised query

Tags: mysql, sql, pentaho, pentaho-cde

I have a problem. i am passing parameter in query using IN clause, but it is giving me error because instead of considering it as a two different values it is considering it as a one single value, so how can i handle this on sql level?

> select * from table where name in ('abc','xyz'); this will work fine.

instead of this it is considering it as a

> select * from table where name in ('abc,xyz'); this will give error

my parameter values are as below 
basically i am checking conditional filtering. that why written this logic if values are there then consider this parameter in where clause or else ignore it.

> case when '${thera}' <> '''' then 
>       (         ccp.name in ('${thera}')    ) ELSE 1=1 END

Note : for avoiding conditional filtering any better approach is their then please suggest that to.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't pass a list as a parameter.  You can use `find_in_set()` instead.

Comment: Not working.
Can you tell me how should i have to write? something like this?
case when '${thera}' <> '''' then ( ccp.name find_in_set ('${thera}') ) ELSE 1=1 END

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed pass a list of values as a parameter. But you need to use a *Custom Parameter* component.

For your example, you can create a Custom Parameter named `parThera`, and then for initial value you can use the expression as you would do in javascript:

```
['abc','xyz']
```

Another option is to use a function expression, like:

```
function (){
  return "A list of words".split(" ");
}
```

Then, on the SQL query, add this parameter, using `thera` as argument name, and the parameter `parThera` as value.

Now you can use it inside the SQL like in your first example:

```sql
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE name IN (${thera})
```

The parameter will be expanded to `'abc','xyz'`, thus making it usable inside the `IN (...)` clause.

> Note: on the SQL parameters setup, you need to specify that this parameter is of type **StringArray**. Otherwise it will not expand correctly.